# Best way to have a Node.JS server keep updated with a FireBase database in real time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a Node.JS server set up that is able to read and write data from a FireBase database when a request is made from a user.

I would like to implement time based events that result in an action being performed at a certain date or time. The key thing here though, is that I want to have the freedom to do this in seconds (for example, write a message to console after 30 seconds have passed, or on Friday the 13th at 11:30am).

A way to do this would be to store the date/time an action needs be performed in the database, and read from the database every second and compare the current date/time with events stored so we know if an action needs to be performed at this moment. As you can imagine though, this would be a lot of unnecessary calls to the database and really feels like a poor way to implement this system.

Is there a way I can stay synced with the database without having to call every second? Perhaps I could then store a version of the events table locally and update this when a change is made to the database? Would that be a better idea? Is there another solution I am missing?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
How I currently initialise the database:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var database = firebase.database();
```

How I then get data from the database:

```
await database.ref('/').once('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            if(childSnapshot.key === userName){
                userPreferences = childSnapshot.val().UserPreferences;
            }

        })
    });
```

Comment: Firebase has two databases: Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore, and it's not clear which one you're using. Luckily both support realtime listeners, which seem key to what you need. But I'm having a hard time understanding where you are stuck. Can you edit your question to show more of the code and data that reproduces where you are stuck?

Comment: The part that has me 'stuck' is more to do with the planning side of this project. I am using a realtime database and have added the relevant code to the question. Am I misunderstanding how this works? When I do firebase.database() is this actually already being updated in realtime? Meaning I can get a snapshot of the database every second without it being too demanding?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase `once()` API reads the data from the database once, and then stops observing it.

If you instead us the `on()` API, it will continue observing the database after getting the initial value - and call your code whenever the database changes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to develop an application for scheduling. If that's the case you should check out [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule).

> Node Schedule is a flexible cron-like and not-cron-like job scheduler
> for Node.js. It allows you to schedule jobs (arbitrary functions) for
> execution at specific dates, with optional recurrence rules. It only
> uses a single timer at any given time (rather than reevaluating
> upcoming jobs every second/minute).

You then can use the database to keep a "state" of the application so on start-up of the application you read all the upcoming jobs that will be expected and load them into `node-schedule` and let `node-schedule` do the rest.

Comment: This sounds very useful! Thank you I will take a look!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud solution for scheduling a single item of future work is Cloud Tasks.  Firebase is part of Google Cloud, so this is the most natural product to use.  You can use this to avoid polling the database by simply specifying exactly when some Cloud Function should run to do the work you want.

I've written a [blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) that demonstrates how to set up a Cloud Task to call a Cloud Functions to delete a document in Firestore with an exact TTL.