# Print message at the right time

Tags: javascript, node.js

next ... I have a code, and I want it to do a certain action every day at a specific time.

As I am learning JS, I believe I have to use a loop for this (I don't know), but I would like your help.

My code:

```js
data = new Date
horas = data.getHours()
minutos = data.getMinutes()

if(horas === 11){
console.log('Okay!')
}
```

In this code (which is in the node), it only prints "okay" and rightly if I'm running at 11am. How do I run the code and only print it when the time is right? Example:

I execute the code at 11 am, but with the condition of if `getHours () === 12`, how can I make it print at the terminal when it is 12 pm?

Comment: You need to instantiate `Date` `constructor` like `new Date()`

Comment: @brk You don't. It should work just fine without brackets as well.

Comment: You could set an `Interval` to run every hour and then perform your hour check.

Comment: As I said, I am learning. Can someone show me a code as an example? Thank you guys

Comment: There's a recent question unrelated, but has an answer featuring a tool called 'node-schedule' (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464388/best-way-to-have-a-node-js-server-keep-updated-with-a-firebase-database-in-real), (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) which may help with time-activated tasks.

Comment: @VasilyHall the OP didn't mention nor tag `nodejs`.

Comment: @MatheusNascimento are you trying to run this on the server side or the client side?

Comment: Server @msmolcic

Comment: @h0r53 the line 'In this code (which is in the node)' is where I got the idea it might be Node.js, may be mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution with [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule):

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
 
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 11 * * *', function() {
  console.log('Okay!')
});
```

`0 11 * * *` is read as every `11:00` (11th hour and the first minute everyday)

---

**OR**

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

const rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.hour = 11;
rule.minute = 0;

const j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    console.log('Okay!')
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As @h0r53 said, you'll need a `setInterval` call.

```
setInterval(() => {
  data = new Date()
  horas = data.getHours()
  minutos = data.getMinutes()

  if(horas === 11){
    console.log('Okay!')
  }
}, 60000)
```

This will run once every minute and log "Okay" whenever it's in the target hour. If you want it to only run once an hour you can change the timing or check for a specific minute as well.

Comment: It's worth noting that this interval executes every 60000 milliseconds, or basically once per minute. If you don't want the console log to continue every minute throughout the hour you'll need to set a flag indicating the event has already been logged this hour, and unset the flag when `horas !== 11`.